# derivation of objective function in linear regression

Tags: regression, linear, loss-functions

In linear regression, we have a very simple task. This is to measure a distance between Y and y_hat, where y_hat for sake of simplicity is multiplication of X and w.

So we can say: Error = Y-y_hat = Y-X*w

If we consider partial derivative of error/w and optimize it, we get 0=-X

But this is quiet strange isn't it? So my question is, what is the proper way of understanding objective function and how to optimise it.

Comment: Note that your "distance" measure can have negative values, so it isn't a distance at all.   Think of a different distance measure... one related to linear regression, for which parameter estimates are often formed using ordinary least squares (OLS).

Comment: @jbowman Yes, I know it... But let's assume you fall from the Mars and you know only how to derive functions and optimise it. What prior knowledge should you cover to define good objective functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strange thing here is that you think of $d(y,\hat y)\equiv y-\hat y$ as the distance between $y$ and $\hat y$. However, given this definition, $d$ is not a distance measure as $d(y,\hat y)$ can be negative for certain values on $(y,\hat y)$ (e.g., (1, 2)). The proper way to think about this is that in general, regression is about minimizing the error we make when we base our predictions of $y$ on $\hat y$, which can be described by a loss function $L$ that takes $y$ and $\hat y$ and gives us the loss in basing our predictions of $y$ on $\hat y$. Possible loss functions satisfy $L(y,\hat y)=(y-\hat y)^2$ and $L(y,\hat y)=|y-\hat y|$.